# Run commands in cmd as administrator using c++

Tags: c++

How can I run command in cmd as administrator using c++?
I have virus on my notebook that changes DNS address every 20-30 minutes. I want to create program to change DNS address by myself.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
system("netsh interface ip set dns “Ethernet” static 192.168.0.1");
return 0;
}
```

I need to run this command as admin. Please help.

Comment: runas. (But why not remove the virus?)

Comment: And a bat would not work?

Comment: Log in as administrator and then run it.

Comment: That's actually gold. Fight fire with fire!

Comment: @iehrlich maybe it's a modern rendition of [Core War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War).

Comment: @doctorlove I have tried to remove virus, but my antivirus can't find any of them on my computer. I need to reinstall windows, but for now I want to create simple program.

Comment: @manni66 I am new in programming I don't understand a lot of things, this is why I am here.

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov I think what manni66 meant is that you probably just want to use a batch script running in the background issuing the exact comment you mentioned periodically

Comment: btw antivirus sometimes can't help you out so that you have to manually find, catch and remove the virus or (much better) use FreeBSD or something

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov, look into Task Scheduler. You can set up a repeating task, and there is an option to make it run as administrator. This would be the fastest way to do what you want, and there is lots of documentation for this tool. Once you have done that, you could try uploading the virus EXE file to https://www.virustotal.com/, it would be very interesting to look at the link you get from that (it's anonymous and nobody can then download the virus).

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov, also, if you wanted to tell your antivirus provider about this new virus or you wanted to tell the services that VirusTotal shows no detection for, this search may be useful: https://www.google.com/search?q=submit+virus+sample

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov: also, about your question - I'm not sure if you are actually running the exact code you have pasted, but I have noticed that the quotes surrounding "Ethernet" are nonstandard, and will not be interpreted by Windows correctly. I'm not sure if you actually *need* those quotes, but if you do, you will need to *escape* them, like `system("blah blah \"Ethernet\" blah blah");`. This is called string escaping.

Comment: @MuhammadaliNazarov why do you need a C++ program at all? You are only starting a script. If your problem is a virus than you can simply write a batch file with your comands.